# How to configure iptables to set public IP for outgoing traffic from private IP

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

I have multiple public IPs at home:

```
1.1.1.1 (main IP)
2.2.2.2 (additional IP)
```

In my local network, I have two computers, let's say

```
192.168.1.1 (PC1)
192.168.1.2 (PC2)
```

Infront of the computers I have an Ubuntu machine acting as Firewall. I was able to forward public traffic to `2.2.2.2` with the following rule in Ubuntu:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p all -d 2.2.2.2 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
```

When PC2 is browsing in the internet, it still uses the main IP `1.1.1.1`. Which iptable rule should I add to make sure PC2 also uses the IP `2.2.2.2` when browsing the internet?